# Python selenium get the value copied to clipboard

Tags: python, selenium

There is a button on the page which when I clicked copies, say a value to the clipboard.

I'm trying to store that value in a variable with python selenium this way:

```
# Clicking the button using xpath will copy the value to Clipboard

value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/button').click()

# I try to print the value using

print(value)
```

But I get the result as `None`.

Kindly help me in doing this in correct way.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, printing the `value` is not meaningful because `click()` function in Selenium doesn't return anything. You can store the text on your clipboard to a variable with this snippet:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()  # to hide the window
variable = root.clipboard_get()
```

Comment: When I click that button, a value is copied to clipboard. How can I store that value in a variable?

Comment: It's very easy with the use of ```tkinter``` which is a module that comes with python 3, so you do not need to do installation separately.

Comment: Thanks.. that's what I wanted.

Comment: Just wanted to ask.. Can this thing also be done using pyperclip module?

Comment: Yes, but ```pyperclip``` module is not one of the default modules of python. Therefore you would have to install it with ```pip```, which seems unnecessary for such a little task.

Comment: You would also want to hide the main window....

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks @Muhteva for the solution, it helped me. But when I tried it with the headless mode I took this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: CLIPBOARD selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined
```

PS: it works well when the headless mode is disabled

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).