# Copy the link, once click on a button - selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, clipboard

There is a button on the page that when I clicked copies a link. check the below image

[image]

I'm trying to store that link in a variable with python selenium this way:

```
surl=ii.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[str({row+1})]/td[6]/div/div/span/div/button')
furl = surl.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "c")

print(furl)
```

But I get the result as **None**. What is the issue here, Could someone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking that button the link is copied to the clipboard.
There are several ways to get the text content from clipboard with Python. For example try this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk

surl=ii.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[str({row+1})]/td[6]/div/div/span/div/button')
surl.click()
link = Tk().clipboard_get()
print(link)
```

Comment: It worked but how can I close popping Tk# windows?

Comment: Try any of these https://www.google.com/search?q=close+popping+tkinter+window&rlz=1C1GCEJ_enIL999IL1000&oq=close+popping+tk&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j33i160l3.9756j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thank you, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469371/python-selenium-get-the-value-copied-to-clipboard

Comment: Great! I'm happy I could resolve your problem :)